# Add Enhanced Video Renderer Stream

Tags: c++, video, directshow

I have a Direct Show program that utilizes the EVR. I would like to add another video stream that basically inserts a picture-in-picture box over the main video stream but can't quite figure out how to do it:

```
// When this is called, the graph is already running with the EVR
// displaying a web cam in stream 0
HRESULT CVideoControl::AddVideoStream(wchar_t* file)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CComPtr<IMFMediaSink> sink;
    CComPtr<IMFStreamSink> stream;
    //hr = pEVR->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMFMediaSink), (void **) &sink); <- FAILS
    hr = MFCreateVideoRenderer(__uuidof(IMFMediaSink), (void **) &sink);
    hr = sink->AddStreamSink(1234, NULL, &stream);
    CComPtr<IMFGetService> service;
    hr = pEVR->QueryInterface(&service);
    CComPtr<IMFVideoMixerControl> mixer;
    hr = service->GetService(MR_VIDEO_MIXER_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&mixer));
    MFVideoNormalizedRect rect = { .25, .25, .5, .5 };
    hr = mixer->SetStreamOutputRect(1234, &rect);
    hr = m_pGraph->RenderFile(file, NULL);
    return hr;
}
```

Everything returns S_OK except the SetStreamOutputRect, which returns "The stream number provided was invalid."

I'm also dubious about the `MFCreateVideoRenderer` call, as this is a direct show program, not media foundation.

I'm pretty sure I am way oversimplifying this, but can't find much documentation on this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965247(v=vs.85).aspx

In a directshow program you need to create EVR with CoCreateInstance and then use it's IEVRFilterConfig interface as explained in the link above:

The EVR filter starts with one input pin, which corresponds to the reference stream. To add pins for substreams, query the filter for the IEVRFilterConfig interface and call IEVRFilterConfig::SetNumberOfStreams. Call this method before connecting any input pins. Pin 0 is always the reference stream. Connect this pin before any other pins, because the format of the reference stream might limit which substream formats are available.